# Extracting Data from one Excel Doc to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I cannot do screenshots due to proprietary information being in the data set.

Here is what I am trying to do and I am looking for the formula to help me do it. In Excel Doc 1 there contains Store and Region. Store is located in Column A and Region is located in Column L. I can of course move this around if need be.

In Excel Doc 2 only store number is available; however, I need the region in this document as well. How do I get the region in Excel doc 2 to match what is in Excel Doc 1?

Comment: Try the `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: Could you provide a sample screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

**I'm assuming that the Store Numbers are written in Column A in Sheet 2.**

Enter this Formula in Cell `B2` of `Sheet 2` and fill it down.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:L40,12,FALSE),"No Match")
```

**Note,**

- `12`, in the above Formula is Column position 
  for `Column L`.
- `IFERROR` will return *No Match* text when Formula doesn't found *Store Number* in Sheet 1.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*